# Convert FOR statement to FORALL in PL/SQL Oracle

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql, null, forall

Is this possible to convert this "for" in "forall" ?

```
FOR  tempCounter in tempCollection.FIRST .. tempCollection.LAST LOOP
  IF tempCollection(tempCounter).execactstockkey IS NULL THEN
    RETURN;
  END IF;
  INSERT INTO  tbexectempactstock VALUES  tempCollection(tempCounter);
END LOOP;
```

Also I tried this

```
FORALL tempCounter in tempCollection.FIRST .. tempCollection.LAST
  INSERT WHEN tempCollection(i).execactstockkey IS NOT NULL
    THEN INTO tbexectempactstock VALUES tempCollection(tempCounter);
```

But it pops up me missing SELECT KEYBOARD

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that you can transform this conditional statement into a `FORALL INSERT`. A `FORALL MERGE` might be possible, but the best way is in my opinion to do it in a single insert:

```
INSERT INTO tbexectempactstock
SELECT * FROM TABLE(tempCollection)
 WHERE execactstockkey IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This syntax works for nested tables of object types, prior to Oracle Database 12c. As of 12.1, you can also use TABLE with associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use not null clause

```
   FORALL tempCounter  IN tempCollection.FIRST .. tempCollection.LAST
    INSERT INTO tbexectempactstock 
    SELECT
        *
    FROM TABLE(tempCollection(tempCounter))
    WHERE tempCollection(tempCounter).execactstockkey IS NOT NULL;
```